# Is there a way to create a list in python with both continuous and discrete values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, set

I am looking for a way to create a mixed list in Python like this

```
List A = [(7-12), (18-23), 45, 67, 43]
List B = [(15-17), 67]
```

Is there also a function in which I could check if List B fits inside List A? and if it doesn't fit, print out the elements that didn't fit in the list?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `(7-12)` is `-5`, should listA be`[-5, -5, 45, 67, 43]`?

Comment: In what sense are the elements of these lists "mixed". What do you mean by "fits inside"?

Comment: @mozway {7-12} is an interval of values that are between 7 and 12 (both inclusive)

Comment: @Stuart In List A, {7-12} represents all values between 7 and 12 (both inclusive), which makes it 'continuous' while values like 45, 67 and 43 are discrete. When I say "fits inside", I mean List B should be a subset of List A

Comment: I would suggest doing an intro to python programming course as you don't appear to understand basic syntax. We all had to start somewhere

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: @mozway In the above example List B would be a subset of List A, so it would perfectly fit.

Comment: you intervals look like a python `range` or numpy `arange`.  Indexing can also use `slice` `[1:4]`

Comment: @giantjenga There's a big difference between {7-12} and (7-12) in Python. I suggest you show some actual Python code to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) you can use an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html), then compare the pairs:

```
listA = [(7,12), (18,23), 45, 67, 43]
listB = [(15,17), 67]

A = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,x)
                                  for x in listA])
# IntervalIndex([(7, 12], (18, 23], (45, 45], (67, 67], (43, 43]],
#               dtype='interval[int64, right]')

B = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,x)
                                  for x in listB])
# IntervalIndex([(15, 17], (67, 67]], dtype='interval[int64, right]')

out = all(any(b<=a for a in A) for b in B)
```

output: `True`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by discrete and continuous. Do you want the open interval (7, 12) ?

Regarding the second question. Yes there is :)

I would turn the list into sets and compare them and convert them back into lists if necessary. Se the link for to see the set operations.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-operations-union-intersection-difference-symmetric-difference/

Hope it'll helps

Comment: The Interval (7,12) includes values like 7, 7.1, 7.2, 8, 9 ,10.5, 12. It's a range of all real numbers between 7 and 12 (end points inclusive). Sorry for using the wrong notation.